# `react-native start` takes long time

Tags: react-native, watchman

Working with react-native on Windows becomes more difficult with each passing day.

At the beginning everything was working fine (`"react-native": "^0.18.0-rc"`). Then I upgrade react-native about four months later than I started. React-Native became runs more slowly. Even so it became slower, I continued to improve my project.

Some day, I read that "React Native 0.22 ships with Hot Reloading!" Then I tried it out immediately. It didn't work stable on Windows. I tried recently. Unfortunately everything is the same.

I've updated React-Native to `0.27.0-rc2`. The packager works extremely slow. 
Then I tried to init a fresh project and moved the project into the new initialized project. This process has reduced the packager working time to 169 seconds from 293 seconds. Then I tried to downgrade RN version to `0.26.2` stable. Everything seems the same.

Even `finding dependencies` phase takes 177 seconds. This is a real disaster for me.

Is there any chance to make faster the React-Native packager on Windows?

*After upgrading to 0.27.0-rc2:*
[image]

*After fresh initialization:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After hours, it reached an acceptable time. It may thanks to caching.

Packager time......: 87 seconds 
find dependencies: 5 seconds